# Expire a token in 24 hours - django-rest-knox

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using django-rest-knox for token authentication in my Django REST Framework app. What I want is to make the token expire only if 24 hours are passed. Is there any setting that it can make this thing happen.
Thanks

Comment: This is covered the settings for the package, at https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/settings/

Comment: Yeah I came to know about it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `settings.py` you should do:

```
from datetime import timedelta

REST_KNOX = {'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=24)}
```

Comment: Do you know how to set it to infinite??